# How can I tween between multiple colors for this background?

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I am new to three.js and am trying to tween multiple shades of the 000001 that is currently set as the background color. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000001 );
```

Comment: take a look at http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/ and https://medium.com/@lachlantweedie/animation-in-three-js-using-tween-js-with-examples-c598a19b1263 for guidance.

Comment: make threejs background transparent and get in touch with CSS of underlying DIV element